# How to set up UserTransaction with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, wildfly, jta

I have a mySQL database for manage user information, and I am using JTA datasource for my mySQL database, here is what the persistence.xml look like:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="SensorCloudPU" transaction-type="JTA">
      <jta-data-source>java:/SensorCloudPU</jta-data-source>
<!--      <non-jta-data-source>java:/SensorCloudPU</non-jta-data-source> -->
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.AnomalousInfo</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.Code</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.Device</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.Executable</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.Group</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.GroupAlert</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.GroupRule</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.GroupRuleDefinition</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.GroupRuleStatus</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.Node</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.NodeAlert</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.NodeRule</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.NodeRuleDefinition</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.Organization</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.PastGroupStatus</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.Trace</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.TrainingSession</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.User</class>
      <class>com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.Role</class>
      <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value = "false" />
         <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer" value="allow"/>
         <property name="transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
         <property name="jta.UserTransaction" value="java:jboss/UserTransaction"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I have an endpoint like this:

```
@Path("/delete")
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response deleteUser(@FormParam("organization_id") Integer organizationId,
      @FormParam("username") String username) throws JsonProcessingException, NotSupportedException,
      SystemException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, RollbackException,
      HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException, NamingException {
    Organization org = organizationDAO.getByOrganizationId(organizationId);
    userDao.deleteUserByUserNameAndOrganization(username, org);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
  }
```

And the DAO is like this:

```
public class userDAO {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "SensorCloudPU")
  protected EntityManager em;

  @Resource
  protected UserTransaction utx;

  public void deleteUserByUserNameAndOrganization(String userName, Organization org)
          throws NotSupportedException, SystemException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException,
          RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException {
        Query q = this.em.createNamedQuery(User.Q_GET_BY_USERNAME_AND_ORGANIZATION);
        q.setParameter("organization", org);
        q.setParameter("user_name", userName);
        User u = this.executeQueryForSingleResult(q);
        if (u == null) {
          return;
        }
        utx.begin();
        this.em.remove(u);
        utx.commit();
      }
}
```

But every time when I load the page and try to delete the from the database, I got this error:

Resource lookup for injection failed: java:jboss/UserTransaction]

UserTransaction [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEJB0137: Only session and message-driven beans with bean-managed transaction demarcation are allowed to access UserTransaction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are primarily concerned with transaction management I suggest that you convert your DAO into an EJB. It only takes one line:

```
@Stateless
public class userDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "SensorCloudPU")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public void deleteUserByUserNameAndOrganization(String userName, Organization org) {
        Query q = this.em.createNamedQuery(User.Q_GET_BY_USERNAME_AND_ORGANIZATION);
        q.setParameter("organization", org);
        q.setParameter("user_name", userName);
        User u = this.executeQueryForSingleResult(q);
        if (u != null) {
            this.em.remove(u);
        }
    }
}
```

and you can see that it simplifies things significantly. EJBs give you JTA transaction demarcation (and rollback if needed) for free.

This will work even if you are building a WAR only deployment.

You could also add `@Stateless` to your JAX-RS endpoint if you want. At the very least you will get a bit more monitoring than you may otherwise have.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use UserTransaction in an EJB, unless you add @TransactionManagement(BEAN)

What TransactionManagement does is

Specifies whether a session bean or message driven bean has container managed transactions or bean managed transactions. If this annotation is not used, the bean is assumed to have container-managed transaction management.

```
@TransactionManagement(BEAN)
public class userDAO {
```